# Unknown circuit component with glass encapsulated contacts

Tags: circuits, electronics

[image]This is an unsoldered circuit component that had two metal pieces that weren't making contact inside a thin glass tube. What is this? I haven't seen anything like it before.

Comment: A photo that has the item in focus would help as would more information, such as they type of circuit the item came from.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks to me like a [reed switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed_switch) (I can't be really sure though because the image is not clear enough).

[image]

A reed switch is an electrical switch operated (usually) by an applied magnetic field.  A common example of a reed switch application is to detect the opening of a door or windows, when used as a proximity switch for a security alarm.

Comment: That's it! Thank you! The image you posted looks exactly like it.

Comment: It's also fairly common to see those used in applications where they are actuated by proximity to a permanent magnet. In fact, The name "reed _switch_" usually is reserved for the permanent magnet use-case. When it's surrounded by a coil of wire, it's more likely to be called a "reed _relay._"